# QEMU fails to initialize NVMe device

Tags: linux, qemu

I want to learn the NVMe driver in Linux, but I don't have a physical NVMe drive. So, I think QEMU is my current only choice. I setup the system in these steps logined as "root":

1. built QEMU-2.2.1 from source code cloned from stable branch

   > git clone -b stable-2.2 git://git.qemu-project.org/qemu
   >   ./configure
   >   --enable-linux-aio --target-list=x86_64-softmmu
   >   make clean
   >   make -j8
   >   make install
2. create an img and install CentOS6.6 into this image:

   > qemu-img create -f raw ./vdisk/16GB.img 16G
   >   qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1024 -cdrom ./vdisk/CentOS-6.6-x86_64-minimal.iso -hda ./vdisk/16GB.img
3. run CentOS6.6 in QEMU with nvme device

   > qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1024 -hda ./vdisk/16GB.img -device nvme

   But it shows the error message below:

   > **qemu-system-x86_64: -device nvme: Device initialization failed.**
   >   **qemu-system-x86_64: -device nvme: Device 'nvme' could not be initialized**
4. I also run the CentOS6.6 in QEMU without nvme device, it just runs very well.

   > qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1024 -hda ./vdisk/16GB.img

So, how can I get more debug information on this error? Or, how can I solve this issue if you also have similar experience?

Thanks,
-Crane

Answer (score 1):

Find the solution: create a img for nvme device, and start qemu like this:

> ```
> qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2048 -hda ./vdisk/16GB.img -drive file=./vdisk/nvme_dut.img,if=none,id=drv0 -device nvme,drive=drv0,serial=foo --enable-kvm -smp 2
> ```

Comment: How did you generate nvme_dut.img ?

Comment: `qemu-img` can be used to create the image. The key but that should be noted is the `serial=` argument to `-device` is mandatory!